# AWS git clone or pull not working and no error message

Tags: git, clone, amazon-web-services

In one of AWS/AMI instance, I'm trying to `git clone ...` it says `Cloning into '<repo name>'...` but it doesn't clone the repository and not showing any error or any other messages, I have also tried with different repositories that are already working at other servers,

I have also tried to upload complete code with `.git` dir, it shows the correct state with `git status` and shows branch with `git branch` but the command `git pull` is not working either nor showing any error message.

UPDATE 1:
I just tried doing git fetch --all, and got the following error:

```
Fetching origin
error: Could not fetch origin
```

UPDATE 2:
When I changed remote origin to use ssh instead of https path, and did git fetch --all or git clone, I got the following error:

```
Fetching origin
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: Could not fetch origin
```

Please note that I am committing to the same repository from my local machine.

Comment: what does 'git remote -v' give you?

Comment: @Nodebody it says `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` since I can't `git clone` I don't have any repo right now

Comment: git remote -v gives the same output on my localhost and on the server, as i have copied the folder with .git folder

Comment: Yep, I thought in the copied directory... anyway what protocol are you using to clone? http, https, ssh?

Comment: Both, the question is in perspective of https. With ssh there is an error. Updating my question with that info too.

Comment: Okay, now that you seem to have some git directory, what does "git remote -v" print? And can you do a ping to the remote git repository? And can you access the repository from your machine using a web browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15146/discussion-between-zzlalani-and-nodebody).